# Python combine two for loops and not over repeat

Tags: python, loops

when we normally do

```
import itertools
for x, y in itertools.product([1,2,3], [1,2,3]):
    print x, y
```

it prints

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

But i want the out put for

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: for x in range(1, 4): print x, x

Comment: are they always the same length?

Comment: yes its always same length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then why use `itertools.product`? This sounds like you just need `zip`.

```
for x,y in zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3]):
    print(x,y)


1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: Yes that is how `zip` works. If I said `zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` it would produce `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`, which is an element-wise pairing from both lists.

Answer (score 2):

why not just use `zip`?

```
for x, y in zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]): 
    ...
```

Or a single loop:

```
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    print x, x
```